# Asyncio server not flushing transport buffer

Tags: python, python-asyncio, tcpserver

I am running an asyncio TCP server using the asyncio.Protocol class. When I am using the data variable in the data_received() function, I am getting all data that has ever been sent over the socket. Is there a way to flush the buffer every time I read from it? Here is my code:

```
def data_received(self, data):
    data = str(data)
    print("Received Data: ", data)
```

The only flush function I can find in the docs only works for the StreamWriter class which I am not using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 3 you can use the `flush` keyword argument of `print`:

```
def data_received(self, data):
    data = str(data)
    print("Received Data: ", data, flush=True)
```

to forcibly flush the stream. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#print).